# comparing rows inside 2 text files ssis

Tags: ssis

I have 2 files as below. TextFile1.txt is the result after ssis package execution. But some rows are missing in this file. The original file which i should get is TextFile2.txt. So i want to compare these 2 files. I want to know the missing rows. File description is as below.
**"TextFile1.txt contains 20 columns  and 31449 rows
TextFile2.txt containts also 20 columns and 32447 rows."**

Comment: use a merge join and then conditional split on null keys

Comment: I tried this but i think i am doing it wrong way. I merge joined all using outer join. So now i am only getting common rows and others are null. Please give a bit more hint. I also thought this way but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your conditional split should test for the null keys coming from the merge join and direct them to the output to show which rows are missing.

[image]